# table is hidden behind img html

Tags: html, image, html-table

My html page contains bg as IMG SRC.

I want TABLE to be on the img in some position.

Actually, how do I make the table show up at the top of the image?

If I use z-index what am I doing wrong?

Note: I see the rest of the table after where the img ends.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="he">
<body>

<head>
   <TITLE>table on img bg</TITLE>
 <script src="include/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <style>
  html 
  {  
  
  } 
  
  h1 
  {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 350%;
  color: white;
  }
  
  #container
  {
  
  }
  
  #header
  {
  
  }
  #content
  {
  
  }
  #footer
  {
  
  }
  .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border-color:#ebaa80;width:1918px;}
  .tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#ebaa80;color:#fff;}
  .tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#ebaa80;color:#ebaa80;}
  .tg .tg-o24q{font-weight:bold;text-align:center}
  .tg .tg-tdef{font-weight:bold}
 </style>
</head>
<div id="container">
 <img src="images/horizontal/bg.jpg" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px;">
 <div id="header">
 <table class="tg">
 <tr>
 <th class="tg-o24q">Hours</th>
 <th class="tg-tdef">1</th>
 <th class="tg-tdef">2</th>
 <th class="tg-tdef">3</th>
 <th class="tg-tdef">4</th>
 <th class="tg-tdef">5</th>
 <th class="tg-tdef">6</th>
 <th class="tg-tdef">7</th>
 </tr>
 <%
  Response.Write "<TR>"
  Response.Write "<td class=tg-tdef>" & "a" & "</TD>"
  Response.Write "<td class=tg-tdef>" & "b" & "</TD>"
  Response.Write "<td class=tg-tdef>" & "c" & "</TD>"
  Response.Write "<td class=tg-tdef>" & "d" & "</TD>"
  Response.Write "<td class=tg-tdef>" & "e" & "</TD>"
  Response.Write "<td class=tg-tdef>" & "f" & "</TD>"
  Response.Write "<td class=tg-tdef>" & "g" & "</TD>"
  Response.Write "<td class=tg-tdef>" & "h" &  "</TD>"
  Response.Write "</TR>" & vbCrLf
  Response.Write "</table>" & vbCrLf
 %>
 <div id="header">
  <img src="images/horizontal/1.jpg" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px;">
  <img src="images/horizontal/2.jpg" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 210px;">
  <img src="images/horizontal/3.jpg" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 440px;">
  <img src="images/horizontal/4.jpg" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 610px;">
  <img src="images/horizontal/5.jpg" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 1090px;">
  <img src="images/horizontal/6.jpg" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 1320px;">
  <img src="images/horizontal/7.jpg" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 1560px;">
 </div>
 
 <div id="content">  
  
 </div>
 
 <div id="footer">
  <img src="images/horizontal/8.gif" style="position: absolute; right: 50px; top: 1595px;">
  <img src="images/horizontal/9.gif" style="position: absolute; right: 565px; top: 1595px;">
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You must to add a correct snippet.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am with Marcos on this one.. Not enough information for us to try to help...

Answer (score 0):

## Corrections

Your code is wrong. The "head" tag should be the first child of the "html" tag and thus a sibling of the "body" tag.

## Solution 1

Additionally to the "z-index" property, add "position: absolute" to create the overlapping effect like this:

```
img { position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: -1; }
```

## Solution 2

You may want to try to delete your "img" tag and replace your "body" tag with the following:

```
<body style="background-image:url(images/example-image-file.jpg)">
```

That would make the whole image the background of the page.

## References

- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_body_background.asp